# unable to create ViewModel - my_package.App cannot be cast to android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I'm trying to create a ViewModel in MainActivity, which observes to some data changes in some singleton component. The goal is to use that ViewModel in a few fragments of this activity. But so far even without involving the fragment yet it doesn't work. The app gets stuck at launch, printing :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my_package.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class my_package.MyViewModel

my_package.App cannot be cast to android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
```

the problem seems to be in the line : `MyCustomSingletonComponent.getInstance().getSomeDataLiveData().observe......`

The Code :

```
public class MyCustomSingletonComponent
{
    public MutableLiveData<CustomClass> someData = new MutableLiveData<>(); 

    private static final MyCustomSingletonComponent instance = new MyCustomSingletonComponent();

    private MyCustomSingletonComponent() {
        someData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public static MyCustomSingletonComponent getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public LiveData<CustomClass> getDataLiveData()
    {
        return someData;
    }

}


public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) 
    {
        super(application);

        MyCustomSingletonComponent.getInstance().getSomeDataLiveData().observe(getApplication(), myData -> {
            ...  
        });
    }           
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        ....
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, an `Application` is not a `LifecycleOwner`, so you cannot pass it to `observe()` on a `LiveData`. Activities and fragments are standard lifecycle owners.

Second, IMHO, a `ViewModel` should not be observing anything. The thing that uses the `ViewModel` does the observing. `MyViewModel` might hold onto the `LiveData`, but then `MainActivity` is the one that observes.

Comment: Regarding your first point, besides that it's not the right way to work with LiveData, is it even possible to do what I intended? I wouldn't have anything to pass to `observe` instead of getApplication()..      Regarding the second, could you please recommend another way to implement what I need? That is, I have a component that holds the current location. Everytime this location gets updated, I need to go to a server api method (either via retrofit or volley, doesnt matter) and then the response should come to two fragments, they are the "true" observers of this whole chain

Comment: My idea was to hace the viewmodel in activity, and the two fragments would observe to it. Inside that viewmodel, it would observe to the location changes in the singleton component, which would in turn trigger an api call everytime the location gets updated. And then the response of the api call in the viewmodel would be observed in the fragments

Comment: @BVtp: You can use `observeForever()`, but then you need to manually unregister that observer. IMHO, that is a code smell for a `ViewModel`. Regarding the rest, getting locations and working with servers are implementation details of `MyCustomSingletonComponent`, assuming that `MyCustomSingletonComponent` is implementing the repository pattern or something along those lines. The `ViewModel` should not be involved in any of that, other than getting a `LiveData` from the repository and holding onto it for your activity/fragment to  use.

Comment: so what if my Location Component would send broadcast with every address update, and the viewmodel would receive that broadcast, and go to the repository with this address, after which it will `setValue` of that response from respository, which in turn make the two fragments receive that response. Would that (a) work and (b) would be architecturally correct/wise?

Comment: @BVtp: I do not think that it would be architecturally correct. I do not know if you can implement that in a way that would be reliable.